# If $a_n=\sin(n^2)$, how to construct (if possible) a subsequence such that $\lim a_{n_k}\rightarrow 0$?

Tags: analysis

For $a_n=\sin(n)$, it can use the [continued fraction method](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1580749/convergent-subsequence-of-sinn) to construct the subsequence, so that $\lim a_{n_k}\rightarrow 0$.

But for $a_n=\sin(n^2)$, how to construct (if possible) a subsequence such that it converges to $0$ ?

Comment: $\sin(314)$ is not close to zero. Can you be slightly more precise in your question? Maybe a $2\pi$ is missing somewhere?

Comment: Consider the convergents in the simple continued fraction of $\pi$. The numerators can be used for the desired subsequence.

Comment: Are you sure about your solution for $a_n =\sin(n)$?

Comment: oh, sorry, I have edited it @coudy jjagmath

Comment: You need to find subsequence $b_{n_k}$ for $b_n = (n^2) mod π$. You can try to use Pigeonhole principle, there must exist distinct $p$ and $q$ such that $|p^2 - q^2 - lπ| < ε$